# "have done A and have put B" or "have done A and put B"

Tags: present-perfect

Essentially I am asking how verbal forms change if connected with 'and'.
The meaning I want to convey is that 'I have done A' and 'I have put B'.
Which of the following are correct semantically and syntactically and how are they different.

> 1. I have done A and have put B.
> 2. I have done A and put B.

Replace 'A' with 'my homework' and 'B' with 'laundry' to sound more natural.

Comment: You would not normally say *put B* in the first place, regardless of what proceeds it. It should be *put B* ***away***, *put B* ***to rest***, or *put be* ***[something]***. It's very rare that nothing should follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would use option 2.

Example:

> I have done my homework and put my textbooks back in my backpack.

(Note that, as 'Jason Bassford Supports Monica' says, it is pretty rare to use "put" as a verb all by itself without some kind of preposition or additional wording, like: "put away", "put back", "put the lid on", etc.)

The helping verb "have" can be stated just once with the first verb ("done"), and when a second participle comes up in the sentence ("put"), you don't need to repeat the "have" because your audience knows to apply the same helping verb to that participle too.

*But*, your first option (repeating the helping verb), is *not* incorrect, and you might want to state your sentence that way for emphasis.

Example:

> "I have made this announcement four times and have gone out of my
>   way each time to make sure that everyone was informed."

You could also say:

> "I have made this announcement four times and gone out of my
>   way each time to make sure that everyone was informed."

The second sentence is a simple statement of fact, but the first one, with its redundant helping verb, sounds a little more emphatic, and the impatient emotional content is more noticeable.

If you repeat both the subject *and* the helping verb, turning the statement into a compound sentence:

> "I have made this announcement four times, and I have gone out of my
>   way each time to make sure that everyone was informed."

it sounds even more emphatic and (in this case) exasperated.

Answer (score 1):

You would use:

> I have done A and put B.

“I have” is common to both so is used only once, especially as it is a simple sentence where the two ideas, “have” and “put”, have the same weight/significance.

You could actually think of this algebraically:

> I have (done A + put B)

In context:

> I have done my homework and put the laundry away.